# Simulate mouse out in webdriverio - javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

Can someone help me in following case:
Have to simulate **mouseOut** in order to have popup displayed.

Actually have to force in **webdriver.io** to simulate that mouse is on the bookmaker tab.

Tried with opening in new tab and pause, and after that closing tab, but without success.

Only works when move (manually) mouse to the **bookmarks tab or URL input field**.
Here is code which I use to open and close new tab:

```
openAndCloseNewTab() {
 browser.newWindow('https://www.google.com');
 browser.pause('9000');

 browser.closeWindow();
 browser.pause(1000);
 browser.switchWindow(/new_post/gu);
```

}

Below screenshots are just to be easier to understand what I am trying to achieve (first screenshot is with popup manually trigered, and second one, where I have to mouse moved in webdriver-io - bookmarks tab)
[image]

[image]

thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried usinig move() ?  
`const actions = driver.actions({async: true});
await actions.move({origin:<locator-of-your-bookmarks-tab>}).perform();`

Comment: Sorry, for late response and thank you - it does worked